# Change maxbuffer length globally ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER

Tags: javascript, exec, child-process, spawn

I want to change in every `exec` call method maxbuffer length.
Something like this options `{maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}`.
Can I do it globally? because I cant know all places where this issue will be in the future, and this is in other libraries code.